# Import error on python package inside django project

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and i have this django project, which actually has to communicate with a python package that my colleague has built. Let's say, the structure is as follows

```
-Mydjangoproject
      -myapp
         -views.py
         -models.py

      -Mydjangoproject
         -settings.py
         -urls.py

      -manage.py

      -db.sqlite3

      -colleagues_python_package
         -package1
            -script1.py
            -script2.py
         -package2
            -info1.py
            -info2.py
```

When I try to run my colleague's **script1.py** which has the following code to import,

```
from colleagues_python_package.package2 import info1
```

it throws me the error

> ImportError: No Module named colleagues_python_package.package2

If run in my colleague's system, this works. Is it because this package is not set in PYTHONPATH. How do I resolve this and explanation? ( and this package has to be inside django project)

Comment: Did you miss the `__init__.py` files?

Comment: No they are available inside all the folders

Comment: Are you using virtual environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found that I have to import using **[dot]**'s. For example, if I want to run the **script1**, I'll have to import **info1** as below

```
from ..package2 import info1
```

Representation is like,

```
1 dots - current folder 
2 dots - current folder's parent 
3 dots - current folder's parent's parent
```

Hope I ain't confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Try importing the module from `python manage.py shell` and see if you will get any errors.